# C - using to pointer to function yield no result

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am creating a program which uses a pointer to function to allow the user to select from 2 options to perform on an array of integers: reverse or randomise. However, the program yield no output when executed. Where did I go wrong?

```
void reverseArray(int arraySize, int a[]);
void randomiseArray(int arraySize, int a[]);
void printArray(int arraySize, int a[], void (*arrayFunction)(int arraySize, int a[]));


int main ()
{

    srand(time(NULL));

    int selection;
    int myArray[] = {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20};

    printf("Enter 0 for reverse, 1 for randomise.\n");
    scanf("%d",&selection);

    if (selection == 0)
        printArray(sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(myArray[0]),myArray,reverseArray);
    else if (selection == 1)
        printArray(sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(myArray[0]),myArray,randomiseArray);
    else
        printf("Please make a valid selection\n");

    return 0;

}

void reverseArray(int arraySize, int a[])
{
    int i,j=arraySize,swap=0;

    for (i=0;i<arraySize/2;i++)
    {
        swap = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = swap;
        --j;
    }

}

void randomiseArray(int arraySize, int a[])
{
    int i,j,swap;

    for (i=0;i<arraySize;i++)
    {
        j = rand()%(i+1);

        if (j!=i)
        {
            swap = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[i] = swap;
        }
    }
}

void printArray(int arraySize, int a[], void (*arrayFunction)(int arraySize, int a[]))
{

    arrayFunction(arraySize, a);

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) 
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

The user selects when function they want to perform by typing either 0 for reverse or 1 for randomise. Based on the decision, a `printArray` function is called with the respective choice.

`reverseArray` is just a generic swap function, and `randomiseArray` uses a Fisher-Yates shuffling algorithm.

I am assuming that the source of my error lies in the `printArray` fucntion, yet I cannot correct it.

Comment: `reverseArray` looks like it can write outside the bounds (on first iteration, `j`  is `arraySize` which is out of bounds), which of course gives you undefined behavior. Does the no-printing happen for both choices of function?

Comment: Adding simple `printf` statements and outputting, e.g.  `i, j` at the point before you randomize and in reverse array can quickly identify where your problems are. Also simply computing `int nelem = sizeof myArray/sizeof *myArray;` after you define `myArray` will prevent multiple calculations of the same value. (a nit here, but adds up if you are calling it `1,000,000` times)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two errors

in reverseArray, `j` should start at `arraysize - 1` or you will be writing one element past the end of the array

```
void reverseArray(int arraySize, int a[])
{
    int i, j = arraySize - 1, swap = 0;

    for (i = 0; i<arraySize / 2; i++)
    {
        swap = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = swap;
        --j;
    }

}
```

And in `randomizearray()`, you assign to `a[i]` twice, instead of using `a[j]` for the final assignment.

```
void randomiseArray(int arraySize, int a[])
{
    int i, j, swap;

    for (i = 0; i<arraySize; i++)
    {

        j = rand() % (i + 1);
        printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
        if (j != i)
        {
            swap = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = swap;
        }
    }
}
```

The first error causes undefined behavior when reversing, the second causes the array to stay the same.  Other than that, the function pointers are setup fine and work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In reverseArray() your index `j` is out of range, it should he `j=arraySize-1`

Other than that it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing outside the bounds of your array, causing UB and in this case "no output":

In `reverseArray`, you must initialize `j=arraySize-1`. Without the `-1` you go out of bounds.